# isSymmetric.matrix {base} vs is.symmetric.matrix {LaplacesDemon} in R

Tags: r, linear-algebra

While trying to write code for a Dirichlet process Gibbs Sampler, using a Normal-Wishart model, I got an error that the matrix I want to use as scale matrix for the posterior is not symmetric. I also tried it by myslef and got the following

```
is.symmetric.matrix(solve(cov(data)))
```

resulted FALSE as output. Also, the cov(data) is a symmetric matrix, which should make solve(cov(data)) a symmetric matrix too. While I tried the base packaage equivalent function for checking whether a matrix is symmetric

```
isSymmetric.matrix(solve(cov(data)))
```

I got a TRUE as an answer

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Thank you both! I used `as.symmetric.matrix` from LaplacesDemon package which fixed the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is how to the two functions measure equality.

`LaplacesDemon::is.symmetric.matrix` uses strict equality

```
 return(sum(x == t(x)) == (nrow(x)^2))
```

This can be problematic when comparing float numbers: see [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)
To use this function, one approach, you could round your covariance matrix.

`isSymmetric.matrix` uses `all.equal`: if the numbers are equal up to a tolerance

```
all.equal(object, t(object), tolerance = tol, ...)
```